# Minimize load cell amplifier noise and interference INA122P

Tags: noise, load-cell

I am trying to simulate car pedals with load cells. For that I wired up 2x20kg load cells and 1x 100kg load cell each wired to a INA122P which join up at a stm32f103c8 blue pill board.

The circuit works but I have two issues. The first problem is that I get a lot of noise and the second is that when I press one pedal I get a bit of input on the other pedals, what was maximum load at one point will then suddenly not be 100% anymore for example.

My first circuit looks like this:

[image: 3 load cell amplifier circuit]

After looking for some solutions I found out that a low pass filter at the Data-Pins of the load cell might help so I changed the circuit to this:

[image]

That did not actually help though since I'm still getting noise. So I'm still left with the question how to fix both interference and noise.

I don't really know a lot about circuits so I'm sorry if I made some obvious mistake or left out important information. I'd appreciate any help!

This is one of the amplifier circuits which connects via wire to the stm32. The 3 upper traces under the IC have been cut.

[image: Circuit]

Load cell wires connect here:

[image]

Comment: Circuit layout is a big contributor to what you describe, posting a picture of your setup might help us understand where the problem would be. I would suggest the the hx711 might have been a better choice for your application - at least there wouldn't be analog signals floating around and you'd get superior resolution as well.

Comment: Sorry, I added a picture of one of the actual boards. I actually copied the design from someone who then mid project decided to only sell boards instead of supplying plans. That's why I'm in a bit of an awkward position trying to figure things out myself.

Comment: Disconnect all but one load cell electrically. Do you still get an interaction between the pedals?

Comment: If by disconnect you mean testing only one load cell + ina122, then yes. I get current on all three Data pins. Otherwise I'm not sure what you mean by disconnect, using diodes in some way?

Comment: No, I mean **disconnect** i.e. remove the electrical wiring between the load cells and the circuitry. Leave only one load cell properly connected. I have no idea what this means: *I get current on all three Data pins* - if you still get interactions then you have a mechanical problem.

Comment: I disconnected all but 1 pedal circuit now and there is not any interference as far as I can tell via multimeter. The software seems to misread disconnected pins that is why I was confused, sorry.

Comment: What time gap are you applying in your code between measurements of 1 channel and the next - try making it longer.

Comment: I'm using [freejoy](https://github.com/FreeJoy-Team/FreeJoy) so I don't really know about any of that. I'm just trying to decouple things correctly and find out what kind of low pass filter I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter idea you have is ok but you could use much larger caps. You can use up to 47uF with your 1k resistor.  This would have a time constant about 1/20 second which should be ok for a brake/gas pedal response.

Also, your schematic show no connection from the ground of your microcontroller to the Vref of your inAmps. Is it there an not shown or did you not complete the circuit?

Finally, add a large cap across each V+ to V- into each load cell. This should minimize your cross-talk across sense lines at other load cells.

Good luck.

Comment: I connected all Vrefs to GND I just didn't want to cross even more wires in the schematic. Can I use electrolytic capacitors for the 47uF? I only have those. Are you talking about the Vin+ and -? What would you categorize as a large capacitor for that? Thank you for the great answer!

Comment: Yes, you can use electrolytic but make sure the black strip (neg side) is connected at Vin(-) for your filter. You can add them in parallel with your current 100nF ceramic caps.  No need to remove them. Keeping the

For s "large" cap across Vin/Vout, a 47uF to 1000uF can all be used.  You'll have to experiment. Close to the load cell is better (short wires). 

Finally, avoid any long wires of your unamplifed signals.  If long (more than 6") cannot be avoided, twist wires together to minimize picking up radio frequency noise.  Big area open loops of wire are bad. Keep things tight & compact

Comment: I've cut the wires of the load cell to about 2" and twisted them so I hope after modifying the circuit with the capacitors the problems are gone. This has been a great help, thank you very much!

Comment: Great.  I'm interested how it works out for you. Please report back good or bad results.

Comment: I added 3 47uF capacitors for each Vout and from Vin+ to Vin- and the result has been great! I even tried 100uF and 220uF but 47uF felt like the best response/noise ratio. Thank you again for your help everything works perfectly now.

Comment: You're welcome... and thank you for taking the time to come back and report results.